# Does this aggregate query require a subquery in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has the following columns:

`user_id int`, `some_dt datetime`, `count int`

None of these are unique keys.

I'm trying to get the `time` and `count` values for a `user_id` where `count` is at the highest. a sample query will look like the following to get the highest count for `user_id` 100 on July 18th, 2016:

`SELECT MAX(count) FROM tbl
   WHERE user_id = 100
   AND DATE(some_dt) = '2016-07-18'`

My problem is, I also want to get the `some_dt` value for the row `MAX(count)` came in. Is there a way to do this without multiple queries?

Comment: Are you sure that no column (or combination of columns) is unique?

Comment: It's entirely possible that a combination of columns is not unique

Comment: In that case, this problem is probably insoluble.

Comment: The other day, you deleted a question that I had answered. Can I ask why? I ended up losing rep for my answer, and it hurt the website as others can't benefit from that question.

Comment: @FrankerZ if I did it wasn't intentional - I deleted a question yesterday I figured out an answer to and thought there was no responses posted. I thought it's impossible to delete a post that isn't answered, anyway?

Comment: I think I may have been in the middle of answering it (I thought I had already posted an answer and was editing it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be you can use having clause

```
SELECT count, some_dt FROM tbl
WHERE user_id = 100
AND DATE(some_dt) = '2016-07-18'
having count = max(count);
```

otherwise you need a subquery  for max

```
SELECT count, some_dt FROM tbl
WHERE user_id = 100
AND DATE(some_dt) = '2016-07-18'
and count = select (max(count) FROM tbl
            WHERE user_id = 100
            AND DATE(some_dt) = '2016-07-18');
```

Comment: The last example you describe returns an entry for every single row that matches the WHERE conditions. Is there a way to just get the row with the `max(count)` and its respective `some_dt`?

Comment: Yeah the problem with that (as in the third example) is `some_dt` is of type `datetime`, and I need the entire `datetime` back and not just the `DATE` representation. The subquery option works (example #2), example #1 fails.

Comment: Well if you need the full some_dt  the third sample is wrong .. then i remove

Comment: The error I get with your first query: In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'test.tbl.count'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: This seem related with the version of mysql you are using  in msql 5.6  should work . in 5.7 not .. then seem you can only use the subquery ..